# get position of marker in google maps

Tags: google-maps

I would like to extract from google maps a list of marker (bus stop), does exits a way to obtain this list? Can i obtain this information using the google maps API?

More precisely i want to extract the bus stop of my local transport company (CSTP):
https://maps.google.it/maps?q=cstp+Campania&hl=it&ll=40.708751,14.758759&spn=0.489271,0.850067&sll=40.674744,14.792656&sspn=0.06119,0.106258&t=h&hq=cstp&hnear=Campania&fll=40.708751,14.758759&fspn=0.489271,0.850067&z=10

I want some information like position of the marker (long,lat) and the name of the bus stop.
Since now i have tried to use python and the googlemaps library, but other way, like javascript with xml or json, will be well accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found out how it should be done. The answer is in the "Nearby Search Requests" of https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests